# Get div coordinates inside parent div

Tags: javascript, coordinates

I have been researching for a while and can't find how to get the correct coordinates from a child div inside of a parent div.

I used getBoundingClientRect() but when the browser is resized the coordinates changed.

```
 var innerDiv = document.getElementById('innerDivID').getBoundingClientRect()
```

For example the parent div is center on the page with a width 1000px and height 500px.

No jquery just pure javascript.

Comment: You could bind a function to the onresize and recalculate the values

Answer (score 0):

You have to recalculate on page resize you could do something like this.

```
onresize = function(){
  var innerDiv = document.getElementById('innerDivID').getBoundingClientRect()
}
```